# How to use NSInvocation to call a class method?

Tags: iphone, nsinvocation

I've a class method which is not declared in the h file, but implemented in the m file.
now I want to call it in another class, since the return value is a int, I can't use selector directly, so I use NSInvocation.

below is what i'm doing:

```
SEL selector = ***;
NSMethodSignature *signature = [classA methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.selector = selector;
invocation.target = [classA class];
[invocation setArgument:(void *)arg atIndex:2];
[invocation invoke];
```

the invoke doesn't succeed, Why?

Comment: if you want to call it in another than shouldn't it be in the .h as well..?

Comment: "the invoke can't succeed" what "doesn't succeed" about it?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I'm doing a unit test, the method are not supposed to be called outside

Comment: LOL that this is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing the arguments, you pass their address, not their value.  Try the following:

```
[invocation setArgument:&arg
                atIndex:2];
```

See [`[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/setArgument%3aatIndex%3a) in the class reference.

Comment: I tried but failed, in fact the argument is a (NSDate *), it is unnecessary to use the '&'

Comment: @Jerrylk look at the example in the link I provided, that also passes an object and uses `&`.